# Ruby =~to check if string matches pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to check if a string is made of only numbers and letters.

```
  def valid?
    "abc#d" =~ /\p{Alnum}/
  end
```

But this returns 0. I expect it to return `nil` since it contains `#` which is neither a letter nor a number.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `def valid?(string) string =~ /\p{Alnum}/ end` would make more sense, considering that, as is, `valid?` will always return `0` (true)` (but you still have to correct the logic, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrong is that you are actually checking:

- whether a string contains any number or letter,

but you wanted to check:

- whether a string does not contain anything other than a number or letter.

You can check it like this:

```
def valid?
  "abc#d" !~ /\P{Alnum}/
end
```

Comment: This returns `true` for an empty string.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Exactly. So what?

Comment: Depends on the requirements.  Question says "string is made of only numbers and letter."  An empty string is not made of only numbers and letters.

Comment: @ExplosionPills You cannot tell whether "an empty string is made of only numbers and letters". The expression "a string is made of only numbers and letters" presupposes that the string is not empty. When the presupposition of an expression is not satisfied, the expression is neither true nor false, it cannot be interpreted. In other words, if an expression "a string is made of only numbers and letters" is true, then that is only when its presupposition is satisfied.

Comment: I don't think it presupposes that at all.  I think that many other people would not presuppose that either even if you consider that case to be correct.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Even if you do not have that presupposition, "an empty string is made of only numbers and letters" cannot be false. Lack of presupposition would only mean that it is vacuously true.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to check to make sure that the string contains *only* numbers and letters:

```
"abc#d" =~ /\A\p{Alnum}+\z/
```

Comment: Thanks. Is your regex equivalent to `/[^\p{Alnum}]/` what's the `+\z` doing?

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton `\A` is similar to `^`, but whereas `^` can match after newlines, `\A` is always at the start of the string.  Similarly, `\z` is always at the *end* of the string.  `+` means one ore more.  From sawa's answer, `!~` just means "do *not* match," but it returns a boolean.

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton Explosion Pills's regex is the negation of `/[^\p{Alnum}]/`. It matches whenever `/[^\p{Alnum}]/` does not match.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer addresses my question, but Sawa's understood what I was after more than I did myself.

Comment: Although, `nil`  will be false, and anything not `nil`, other than `false`, which this will not return, will be `true`.

Comment: @sawa isn't yours also a negation? *not not contains non letters/numbers*?

Comment: Jumbla, when you know rabbits are pink or white, and you want to know if all those in a particular herd (yes, that what it's called) are white, it's often easier to try to spot a pink one than checking to see if they are all white.  I think that applies here.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
"abc#d" =~ /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the `+$` supposed to address?

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

`string !~ /[_\W]/` also works.

```
"abc#d" !~ /[_\W]/ #=> false 
"abc_d" !~ /[_\W]/ #=> false
"abc5d" !~ /[_\W]/ #=> true
```